# Remove or refactor Ember observers manipulating attributes

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Currently, there's a ton of observers throughout an application, and after watching a talk given by Stefan Penner on observers I've been trying to refactor observers to either computed properties or using component lifecycle hooks, but not really succeeding (trying to keep in mind the Data Down Actions Up principle).

But how do you factor out observers on a component whose job it is to say for example go over an array (attribute given to the component) and manipulate it when a different attribute changes.

eg.:

```
// controller.hbs
{{component items=items object=object}}

// component.js
Ember.Component.extend({
 itemsObserver: function () {
  // some logic here that either adds or removes items from
  // for example object.selectedItems (an array) depending on
  // 'items'
 }.observes('items.[]')
})
```

I can't use 'didReceiveAttrs' because it doesn't work when an array is being manipulated (which is what I want to observe). And I wouldn't know how I'd use a computed property here when I don't really need a new property, I just need to manipulate an array on a given object (attribute to the component). But then again, I feel like that's completely contrary to the DDAU principle.

Could anyone enlighten me as so how I need to go about stuff in this situation, especially situations where an observer is used to manipulate another attribute, which in turn is being observed on a different component (it's a mess...).

Comment: Wait, so you're using this component to just manipulate data, without showing it? Explain why you need to manipulate the array at all! And what triggers that.

Comment: Why is `object.selectedItems` not just a computed property dependent on `items.[]`? The idea is that instead of mutating `selectedItems` in the observer, you would compute a new one whenever `items` changes.

Comment: The component is sort of an item selector, it shows the list of items and whether they're selected or not. It's pretty much a modal of sorts that opens. The object with selectedItems on is a 'line' on a graph and there can be multiple lines, which can have different items selected. Those selected items are then used to build the graph. Meaning the object.selectedItems needs to be a property on object because the graph needs to be able to be saved and opened later on.

Comment: Shouldn't the computation/manipulation of `object.selectedItems` be being handled by the caller?